# Could not load file or assembly 'System

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-server

i developed my application using visual studio 2013, then deployed to a window server, current the server has been upgraded to windows server 2022 and my application is breaking and get getting this error:

"Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Http.WebHost, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."

I know its a compatibility issue but hat is the fastest remedy to this.

Comment: How about just deploying all the required assemblies with your application in the first place?

Comment: does the server have the full framework installed?

Comment: I guess it has all

Answer (score -1):

try putting copy local= true in each DDL's properties that say "Could not load file or assembly"